# View contents from .txt file from ASP.NET MVC App_Data directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using an error log function which writes exceptions in a ~/App_Data/ErrorLog.txt file in the following format-

```
Created on: .... + Environment.NewLine
Error Description: .... + Environment.NewLine
Source File: .... + Environment.NewLine
Method: .... + Environment.NewLine
Line: .... + Environment.NewLine
Column: .... + Environment.NewLine
________________________________________________________________________
```

Now i am viewing it in browser. But **NewLine** character disappeared. I used `System.IO.StreamReader` to read the texts.

How can i keep the html as the above format?

Or, Is there any way to open the .txt file directly in browser from **App_Data** directory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you want to put it on the page replace `\n` with `<br />`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("This is a test" + "\n");
sb.Append("This is a test" + "\n");
sb.Append("This is a test" + "\n");

var result = sb.ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");

// put result on the page
// note: StringBuilder works like StreamReader when you call StreamReader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamad. It works. But  @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrorLogs) is needed to render it on razor view page. Anyway, +1.

Comment: Far better to just use css (`whitespace: pre;`)